# Set FacesMessage by Filter

Tags: java, jsf, message, servlet-filters

In my JSF Application, there is a `Filter` which is used to check the authenticati0n process. When the authentication is failed, the filter redirect to `login.xhtml`.

How can I pass the `FacesMessage` to  my login page from `Filter`?

Although, I used below, It is not OK.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null));
```

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter  {
    private FilterConfig config;
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        config = filterConfig;
        servletContext = config.getServletContext();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute(Constants.LOGIN_USER);
        if (user == null) {
            ...
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null));

            String loginView = httpRequest.getContextPath() + Constants.LOGIN_PAGE;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginView);
        } else if (!user.getRole().equals(Role.SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR)) {
            ....
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null));

            String loginView = httpRequest.getContextPath() + Constants.LOGIN_PAGE;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginView);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        servletContext.log("Exiting the filter");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //Nothing to do.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `FacesContext` is created by the `FacesServlet`. When you're inside a filter, it's not been invoked yet. Filters run before servlets. So you can never get a hand to the `FacesContext` in a filter. Plus, faces messages are request scoped, so a redirect would have made them to disappear anyway.

Let the `login.xhtml` set it by itself during a `<f:event type="preRenderView">`. Easiest way would be to let the filter put it temporarily in the session scope.

```
session.setAttribute("message", message);
httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginView);
```

Which you then remove from the session scope in pre render view listener method of `login.xhtml`:

```
String message = (String) externalContext.getSessionMap().remove("message");

if (message != null) {
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with trying to get the FacesContext in a EJB timer.  BalusC has pointed out on multiple threads that it is impossible to do this.  Alternatively you can use a 'ServletContextListener', but the ScheduledExecutorService does not define the scheduling as nicely as an EJB timer.

In any case, one suggestion he made was to actually make a web request to a JSF paged backed by a managed bean to utilize the methods on the application scoped bean that I wanted to set up with a timer.

I mention this, because it seems like you could do something similar, where you pass a param to the JSF page with the message you desire and the users IP address or something.  That page could be backed by a request scoped bean which has an application scoped bean injected into it which stores those in a map with the IP as the key. Then when the user gets redirected to the login page, that page could call a get error message method on a  request scoped bean with the same application scoped bean injected into it which get the error message for that IP or something along those lines.

In any case, I am sure that BalusC's answer is sufficient and more proper than this, but his 'just make a request from the ejb timer' suggestion worked well for me for scheduling method calls on application scoped beans, and I thought I might bring up its possible use here.

@BalusC do you have any idea about the post I am referring to?  I cant find it.